# Receiving error stating that one of the params in my httpRequest is not defined

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

What I'm trying do is take whatever query a user types into the itemSearch field, ping eBay's database, and return the categoryID with the most results. Upon testing however, I'm receiving the following error:

```
[9067:3603] Error: Uncaught Error: Can't set params if there is already a query parameter in the url (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

Removing the quotes around the params didn't fix the problem, and I get the feeling it's because I'm not formatting the params properly in order to take in a value from the objective-C code.

My cloud code is structured like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APP ID GOES HERE*';

        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: url,
            params: {
             'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
             'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0', 
             'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON', 
             'callback' : '_cb_findItemsByKeywords',
             'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice',
             'keywords' : 'request.params.item',

              // your other params
           },
            success: function (httpResponse) {
            // deal with success and respond to query
},
            error: function (httpResponse) {
                console.log('error!!!');
                console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
       });
});
```

And I call the function from within my iOS app like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSNumber *category, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {NSLog(@"Successfully pinged eBay!");
                                        }

                                    }];


    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong.

You have defined your URL as

`url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=*APP ID GOES HERE*'`

but this contains a query string (the bit after the "?"), so you get the error message.

You need to set the url as
 `url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"`

and add

`"SECURITY-APPNAME" : "*APP ID GOES HERE*"`

to your params dictionary